# Phone repeatedly boots (restarts by itself) when kept on hard surface

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-sp

I have got a Xperia SP C5302 which began to show problems from yesterday. It is repeatedly getting restarted by itself whenever I am placing it on any kind of hard surface(ex: table) but works fine when I am holding it in hand or keeping it on top of mattress.

**What I have tried -**

1. Did factory rest couple of times but nothing fruitful.
2. Did a software repair through Sony PC Companion but it didn't work.
3. Tried googling in and around but no good result as of now.

Phone is running stock rom **12.1.A.1.205** **Android – 4.3 Jelly Bean**

Let me know if any further information is required from my side.

Comment: ANY kind of hard surface? Metallic, wood, plastic, all have been explored and the reboot is the same? Is the orientation of the phone a factor? Does it happen equally if the phone is face-down AND on its back? This question seems to lack specific information to guide us to help resolve your issue.

Comment: The face vs. back orientation could lead to understanding. For example, if it occurs consistently on a hard surface WHILE ON ITS BACK, I would investigate the possibility the concealed OFF button inside the back cover may be pressed somehow.

Comment: @wbogacz - Yes, when the phone is kept on any kind of hard surface the phone reboots continuously. But on the same hard surface if kept face down no issues at all. I consulted the Sony service center guy and as per him it's motherboard issue but I doubt that.

Comment: So, I would remove the back cover and investigate the OFF button switch concealed inside. See if it happens without the cover on. If not, the cover is a culprit. Think critically.

Comment: @wbogacz - yes you had guessed it right there was some culprit at the back side of the phone and it was a chip under the battery. The thing is replaced and the phone is running fine now.